# Fake tablayout scoll in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-tablayout

is there a way to scroll back and forth a TABLAYOUT in android? I need it to show the user that the tabs are scrollable

Thank you

```
  TabLayout tabLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an animation for that, it should be easy to implement
check here : https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide#pagetransformer